# How can I root a Lenovo Moto G5?

Tags: lenovo, motorola-moto-g5

I think question is quite clear ... I have a Lenovo Mot G5, and I want to root it (mostly to use AFWall), but I have not yet found any "clean" way to do it. Do you know any way to have it rooted, but not bricked ? ;-)

Comment: Rooting like any other manipulations, has always a potential risk of brick! That's why there are always a disclaimer on every tutorial or guide.

Comment: This guide should help: https://forum.xda-developers.com/g5-plus/how-to/how-to-root-moto-g5-plus-t3579659/amp/